# How can I show the number of facebook likes for a page?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, php

Let me start by saying that I'm a newbie to coding, so it's probable that I'm missing out on the absolute basics...

I'm working on a phtml file (done by professionals) and trying to show the number of likes for different facebook pages.

The query that does it is the following:
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select like_count from link_stat where url='https://www.facebook.com/'&format=json

and I tried to change the following code i found in order to do it

`$fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
        . 'fql?q=SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1=me()'
        . '&access_token=' . $access_token;
    $fql_query_result = file_get_contents($fql_query_url);
    $fql_query_obj = json_decode($fql_query_result, true);`

like this:

```
$fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
    . 'fql?q=select like_count from link_stat where url='https://www.facebook.com/'&format=json';
$fql_query_result = file_get_contents($fql_query_url);
$fql_query_obj = json_decode($fql_query_result, true);
```

I put it into a script and then I tried to call the variable  but received an "undefined variable" error.

I'm not sure what am I doing wrong... 
Is the code alright?
Does it go inside a script, inside a php code block or in something else?
Am I calling the variable correctly?

Sorry if there's any nonsense here, as I said, I'm just getting into it...
Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See, there's a much easier way to obtain basic page data from facebook pages. If you know the ID or the slug of the page, query the graph api like this.

```
$fc = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/40796308305');
$pagedata = json_decode($fc);


?>

Coca Cola has <?php echo $pagedata->likes; ?> likes
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas! That was indeed much easier.
The data I had is the company's facebook page url, however, I found out it also works in your code, for example if I replace the id like that: $fc = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.facebook.com/cocacola');